# Upper case month using dateTimePicker

Tags: .net, winforms

I'm trying to get a dateTimePicker to display the date in the format ddMMMyyyy but in uppercase, eg 01JAN2014 rather than 01Jan2014 which ddMMMyyyy provides.

For clarification, I want the dateTimePicker to display the selected value in this (uppercased) format rather than simply get an uppercase result from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest way to do it.

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

```
    DateTimePicker1.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom
    DateTimePicker1.CustomFormat = Strings.UCase(Format(DateTimePicker1.Value, "ddMMMyyyy"))
```

End Sub

Private Sub DateTimePicker1_ValueChanged(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles DateTimePicker1.ValueChanged

```
    DateTimePicker1.CustomFormat = Strings.UCase(Format(DateTimePicker1.Value, "ddMMMyyyy"))

End Sub
```

Comment: This doesn't work when the month is MAR or MAY due to the month containing the letter M.